# HTML isset and value relation

Tags: php, html, isset

I have a form and fields are name, surname and email.
When I filled name but did not fill surname and email fields I want to name area write name area.(I did not write all codes.)
I hope u can find where is my mistake.

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["name"]));
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<label for="name">Name<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" autocomplete="off" value="<?php if (isset($name)) echo $name; ?>"> <br>
</label>
</form>
```

Thank you guys..!

Comment: I dont't really understand the question... Do you want these empty fields to be automatically filled?. With what information?.

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added an "=" to your value

```
value="<?php if (isset($name)) echo $name; ?>"
```

That should fix it :)

Comment: I can not believe now :D I think I am tired. Thank you so much :)

Comment: no prob please accept as correct answer :)

Comment: value="<?php if .... is present there..
I added a submit button but could not find anything wrong!

Comment: the "=" wasn't present he must have edited it